# Replace a 404-page that appears on google

Tags: google-chrome, google-search, google-search-console

I have a website like this wwww.website.com/URL that is displayed on google when I use a certain keyword.

I have now replaced this url to www.website.com/URL-new. When I search on the same keyword then the old URL is being displayed on Google, which is normal.

My question is: How do I change this OLD URL that is being dispalyed on Google? Is there anything I can do on webmasterstool to speed it up?

I have tried to use the "Get as Google" in webmasterstool to index this new URL. Is there anything more I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use google webmastertools, located here: [HERE](https://www.google.com/webmasters/)
This will help you redirect links to different links and so on. check it out.

Comment: Hi, I have a google webmasterstool, which also is written in the description above. So that is not my problem...... How can I do this redirect-link in webmasterstool?

Comment: Oh sorry i probably misread that then, But if you have replaced the 404 page or said you have changed it there is nothing more you can do. I'm unsure about the time it will take for google to change their search returns.

Answer (score 0):

You ask google to [re-crawl your urls](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en).
[Here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) is information on the 'Fetch as google' they mention.

Comment: I have done fetched the URL but how does google know to replace the old url to this one? There is no field for me to tell google to replace a specific page? Or is google that smart to see that this is the old URL?

Comment: As mentioned in [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8487/how-to-remove-urls-from-google-search-engine) possible duplicate of your question, tough it's a different part of the network, google will be smart enough to do it on their own.  
It just may take a while before the changes to take effect.